# Excel yearfrac() stardate clock

Tags: excel

Im trying to make like a star date from Star Trek get the yearfrac to work with time down to seconds included.
I put this in an excel or google sheets cell and it works great -

`=(YEARFRAC(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),1,1),NOW()))+(YEAR(NOW()))`

to get 2017.283 for the date 13 April 2017. Thats pretty good for what I wanted the year 2017 then "." the percent of the year gone. But to make the bit after the "." more accurate I would like to include the time so its more like 2017.28345.
Is that possible? Then I want to put that formula on a webpage counting up so I can check it like a clock, maybe PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by just doing this -

```
<html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" >
  <title>Current Stardate</title>
 </head>
 <body><center>
<?php
$year = date(Y);
$day = date(z);
$hours = date(H);
$minutes = date(i);
$seconds = date(s);
$stardate = ($day/365)+$year;
$stardatetime = (($day+(($hours+(($minutes+($seconds/60))/60))/24))/365)+$year;
?>
 <p>The current stardate is: </br><?php echo round($stardate, 5) ?></p>
 <p>The current stardate with time is: </br><?php echo round($stardatetime, 8) ?></p>
<p><?php echo "The current earth date is: </br>" . date("l, d M Y. Hm:s") . " hours<br>"; ?></p>
 </center></body>
</html>
```

I need do do an if else {} for a leap year to make it better.
Still if there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, be careful with YEARFRAC. Without specifying the Basis as 1 to use the actual number of days in a year, it will by default calculate the fraction assuming all months have 30 days and there are only 360 days in the year.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YEARFRAC-function-3844141e-c76d-4143-82b6-208454ddc6a8

It's safer and a complete solution to just calculate the fraction ourselves:

```
=YEAR(TODAY())+(NOW()-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))/(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,1,1)-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))
```

This just calculates what fraction now is out of the entire year (which includes time) and adds it to the year. The number of days in the year is calculated using `(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,1,1)-DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1))` to handle leap years.

This formula uses basic functions so you should be able to translate this into other languages without having to link to Excel to access the YEARFRAC function.

Comment: Thanks for you sugestion!